# Security precautions during update

Tags: updates

When you update a new installation for the first time, or update a long time unmaintained OS, do you just enable a software firewall for all incoming connections (and hope there are no obsolete critical bugs hanging there) or do you take any other special security precautions like updating in a separate network to prevent computer worms or any other risks?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Well, if you just update and not visit web pages, your risks are low...

Comment: Thank you. And what about threats related to other devices (work computers, laptops, smartphones, smart tv..) present in a network? On a typical bridged LAN is new computer exposed to them and they could be infected with malware. On the other hand this is what sw firewall droping incoming connections should take care about...